# CSS bootstrap calculate number of columns

Tags: php, css, mysql, html

I'm redesigning my website, and I want to display records in a table 4 rows across and down however many rows it needs.

I've got this script which I've been toying around with for hours, but I'm not getting the desired result. In fact, it's just listing row after row.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-3 col-12-medium">

<?php 
$finditems="Coffee Mugs - Ceramic";
$servername = '';
$username   = '';
$password   = '';
$dbname     = '';
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}$sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE product_subcategory LIKE '$finditems' 
AND(product_active='Y' OR product_active='C' OR product_active='O') AND 
web_sale<>'N' ORDER BY product_name ASC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class=''col-3 col-12-medium'>". $row["product_name"]. "  " . 
$row["product_code"]. " $" . $row["product_p1"]. "<br><img 
src='products/".$row['product_code'].".jpg' width='100' height='100'> 
</div>";
    }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
?>
</div><div>
```

Some of the results may find only 2 items, others might show 10 (depending on the search term). So when there is multiple, it shows the next item to the right, until the row of 4 is filled, then it goes to the next row.
I know i'm missing something for it to calculate it, but I just ain't finding it.

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your probably missing the class as you have this `class=''col-3` double `''` which closes the class attribute....  Just a guess.

Comment: All you need is an <div class="row"></div>, with a while loop that echo's an <div class="col-3"></div>

Comment: Removed the extra '

Comment: I looked at trying to do a loop, but thought that the script somewhere needs to do the count, then work out how many rows are required.

Answer (score 0):

for Medium screen devices It should be like

```
<div class="col-md-3">....</div>
```

include this in all div which you wanted to things in a column. and of you wanted to responsive website just add this

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-3 col-lg-4">....</div>
```

change numbers according your need.